# PowerShell keeps on saying network path not found

Tags: powershell

I created a simple PowerShell code that copies a folder from one computer to another, but I keep getting a "Network path not found" is there something I am doing wrong?

```
# PowerShell Read-Host Input Box
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

Clear-Host
$ComputerName1 = Read-Host "What is the name of your computer?"
$ComputerName2 = Read-Host "What is the name of the computer you are fixing?"
$Yours = $ComputerName1
$Theirs = $ComputerName2
robocopy "\\$ComputerName1\c:\Temp\Test" "\\$ComputerName2\c:\Temp\"
```

Comment: The syntax would be `\\$ComputerName1\C$\Temp\Test` (replace `:` with `$`). Note that this requires you to be a member of the local `Administrators` group on the remote computer.

Comment: *Slaps forehead*  thank you very much, i should have caught that.